# If a subdomain or subdirectory is given a 301 redirect does it affect the parent domain in SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, 301-redirect, subdomain

I have a website running on example.com, but I wish to have abc.example.com that redirects to another domain altogether like example.net.

Is it possible to redirect a subdomain without affecting any SEO of the parent domain?

Comment: Sure! Why not? If there are no important links to your sub-domain then just delete it. Otherwise, a 301 should be fine.

Comment: What links to this subdomain?   Is it your parent domain?  What is currently on this subdoman?   Are you moving content away from it?   I'd think that redirect a brand new subdomain that currently has no links and no content wouldn't change the SEO of your main domain at all, but the case might be different in cases where the subdomain had previously been used somehow.